# Click and Unclick X boxes in VBA excel formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a survey that I want to be simple for the end user.  I have created a document that operates on a Likert scale, where things range from Disagree to Agree on a 6 point scale (with a no answer field).  The questions I have run on rows 3 to 152 and the choices are in cells C:H on each row.  Currently, I have it to where the taker can click on a cell and produce an X in the box, indicating their choice.  I also have it so that they may only click one option in the row, and if they select another option, it removes the first X and places the X in the new cell that they have clicked.

Here is what I want.  Right now, if they place an X in a cell, and click that same X, my code goes through and takes the X away and replaces it again with that same X.  I would like it to replace the clicked X with nothing, so that it can toggle on and off with a click.  I want to keep it so that if they select another cell in the same row, the X in the original cell disappears and the X pops up in the clicked cell, however.  I only want them to be able to select one cell in each row for each question.  Sorry for the length, but I just wanted to be clear.  Here is my code currently.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rInt As Range
Dim rCell As Range

For rw = 3 To 152
  Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw))
  If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw)) > 0 Then
      Range("C" & rw & ":H" & rw).Value = ""
    End If

    For Each rCell In rInt
      If rCell.Value = "" Then
        rCell.Value = "X"
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Set rInt = Nothing
  Set rCell = Nothing
  Cancel = True
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: My advice is to use data validation in a single column instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. Notice I removed your loop; there's no reason to loop through every row when we can pinpoint the row the user selected and focus on that row. I also changed the way `rInt` is set, replaced the `CountA` function with `.Find`, and wrapped the entire procedure with a test to see whether the user has selected a cell in our predefined range (so the code doesn't needlessly run when other cells are selected).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Only run the code if the user selected a cell in our defined range:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:H152")) Is Nothing Then
        'Declare variables
        Dim rInt As Range
        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim rw As Long
        Dim xLoc As Range

        Set rInt = Me.Range(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "C"), Me.Cells(Target.Row, "H"))
        If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
            'Look for a response in our answer range
            Set xLoc = rInt.Find("x")
            If Not xLoc Is Nothing Then
                'If there was a response and the response was in the same column _
                'we selected, wipe the response and exit the sub.
                If Target.Column = xLoc.Column Then
                    rInt.Value = vbNullString
                    Exit Sub
                'Else, wipe the previous response and add the new response
                Else
                    rInt.Value = vbNullString
                    Target.Value = "x"
                End If
            'If there were no previous responses...
            Else: Target.Value = "x"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much for your time, this works perfectly.  I appreciate it so much; you really did me a service today...

Answer (score 0):

All you need here are radio buttons that are linked to a cell and then edit the click code.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Range("D3:H3") = False
    Range("C3") = True
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Range("C3") = False
    Range("D3") = True
    Range("E3:H3") = False
End Sub
```

Then format the cells to make the text the same color as the background and use conditional formatting to change the color of the cell the radio button is in front of by referencing the TRUE or FALSE, very nice for the user and easy.

I'm guessing you haven't used them before so just so you know, you go to the developer tab, I always use the ActiveX radio buttons. Then use design mode to edit the properties of the option button, and change "GroupName" to link any the radio buttons together where you only want one to be clicked by naming them with the same group name.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  :)  My spreadsheet is already made, and I have an extensive amount of additional worksheets with formulas and charts derived from the X's the user inputs on the first page.  It would be more work to go back and redo all of that based on radio buttons.  I appreciate the suggestion, though!

Comment: you could still just replace my "True" and "False" with "X" and "", and you'd have all the Xs where you need them

Comment: if you find my answer helpful, please vote it up and accept the answer. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Sorry, I was really hoping that someone could edit my vba code with three or four lines of code, rather than having to go through and change my entire document that I spent the past three weeks creating.  But thank you very much for your time and your answer! :)